# SpiceDB relation tuples left in db

Tags: postgresql, spicedb

I'm using [spicedb](https://authzed.com/docs/) with postgres database, I've noticed that when I delete a Relation the corresponding tuple is left in the `relation_tuple` table and the value of the column `deleted_xid` is set to transaction id.

Are those records to remain there forever? When will they be actually deleted?

I'm worrying that in a relative short time the table will be clogged with useless records...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement "time-traveling queries", SpiceDB's Postgres datastore implementation actually retains data for a period of time after deletion.

How long this data is available, how often garbage collection is conducted, and how long until garbage collection times out are all configurable.

From the `spicedb serve --help` usage:

```
  --datastore-gc-interval duration            amount of time between passes of garbage collection (postgres driver only) (default 3m0s)
  --datastore-gc-max-operation-time duration  maximum amount of time a garbage collection pass can operate before timing out (postgres driver only) (default 1m0s)
  --datastore-gc-window duration              amount of time before revisions are garbage collected (default 24h0m0s)
```

If you're curious, you can dive deeper into the implementation by reading this particular file: https://github.com/authzed/spicedb/blob/v1.25.0/internal/datastore/postgres/gc.go